# How to set values of succeeding rows based on dynamic condition pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following column in a dataframe, what I would like to do is set order type to all succeeding rows based on if the row is under `BUY IN AMOUNT`, `SELL IN AMOUNT` or `SELL IN UNITS`.
Meaning all orders succeeding for example `BUY IN AMOUNT` should get the value `FUS`. How can this be archieved?

```
Orders
BUY IN AMOUNT
X
X
SELL IN AMOUNT
X
X
SELL IN UNITS
X
X
```

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Orders':['BUY IN AMOUNT','X','X','SELL IN AMOUNT','X','X','SELL IN UNITS','X','X']})
```

Desired output is the following:

```
Orders             TYPE
BUY IN AMOUNT
X                  FUS
X                  FUS
SELL IN AMOUNT
X                  FUD
X                  FUD
SELL IN UNITS
X                  FUD
X                  FUD
```

Comment: why are strings (`'SELL IN AMOUNT'`) and numerical values (`X`) mixed together? Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (one we can copy and paste), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result?

Comment: Is it possible to find different `BUY IN AMOUNT` or similar rows ?

Comment: This is because this data is parsed from a pdf, that's why the data is a mess which I'm trying to clean.

Comment: Is `X` a string?

Comment: Still please provide an MRE. In particular, what are the `X` values (type, content).

Comment: X values are strings, everything is represented as strings. The example provided represent MRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `numpy.select` + `ffill` to fill in values depending on where BUY and SELL are; then `mask` the overfilled rows:

```
import numpy as np
cond = [df['Orders'].str.contains('BUY'), df['Orders'].str.contains('SELL')]
df['Type'] = np.select(cond, ['FUS','FUD'], pd.NA)
df['Type'] = df['Type'].ffill().mask(cond[0] | cond[1], '')
```

Output:

```
           Orders Type
0   BUY IN AMOUNT     
1               X  FUS
2               X  FUS
3  SELL IN AMOUNT     
4               X  FUD
5               X  FUD
6   SELL IN UNITS     
7               X  FUD
8               X  FUD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping dictionary, and a mask:

```
d = {'BUY IN AMOUNT': 'FUS', 'SELL IN AMOUNT': 'FUD', 'SELL IN UNITS': 'FUD'}

s = df['Orders'].map(d)

df['TYPE'] = s.ffill().where(s.isna(), '')
```

Alternative:

```
d = {'BUY': 'FUS', 'SELL': 'FUD'}
s = df['Orders'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(d)})', expand=False).map(d)
df['TYPE'] = s.ffill().where(s.isna(), '')
```

Output:

```
           Orders TYPE
0   BUY IN AMOUNT     
1               X  FUS
2               X  FUS
3  SELL IN AMOUNT     
4               X  FUD
5               X  FUD
6   SELL IN UNITS     
7               X  FUD
8               X  FUD
```